# PyVISA read closes before transfer has finished

Tags: python, visa

I am writing a code in python to communicate with scopes through pyvisa.
Sometimes happens that during the transfer of data from the scope to the pc via ethernet connection, not all the data are transferred.
I open the connection with the scope as a SOCKET connection, as indicated in the manual:

```
inst = visa.ResourceManager().open_resource("TCPIP0::<ip_address>::<port>::SOCKET")
```

Everything runs properly except for data transfer.
I ask for data via the command `inst.write('channel1:data?')` as reported in the manual and then I read the data with `inst.read()`. But if I compare the number of points indicated in the data header with the length of the data array I obtain from the `read()` method I get a different result, not all the data is transferred. I tried to enable termination characters to the read operations and they work, but when I read data I get a warning from VISA saying that the string does not end with any termination character.

Is there a way to tell peeves when stop reading? Is there a way to force the read time to be longer?

Thanks